# Android - Fragment and layout params set PROGRAMMATICALLY

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

I'm having trouble setting the params in my application.

I have two fragments added dynamically, with no R.id values, just R.layout ones.

I want that the second fragment gets added Below the first.

Everything is in a RelativeLayout.

How should i set RelativeLayout.BELOW parameter? I don't have the id of the first fragment since it hasn't got an id explicitly. Will getId() work?

Until now, no error occurs but my fragment gets not shown below the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put two `FrameLayout`s inside your `RelativeLayout` with the proper layout params already, then you can just add your fragments to those instead.